# Exit status of command in pipeline

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, ksh, exec

I have come across this code but cannot understand **`exec >&p`**

edit 1 to my understanding :

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh
exec 4>&1               ## standard output is first saved as file descriptor 4
tail -5 >&4 |&          ## spawn it as co process
exec >&p                ## output of co-process is moved to standard output
cat /etc/passwd         ## this can be any command like ps aux
exitcode=$?
exec >&- >&4            ## standard output is closed using >&-
wait
echo exitcode = $exitcode
exit 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The special redirection `>&p` in the `ksh93` shell redirects the standard output stream into the standard input of the command currently running as a co-process.

In the example given, the `tail -5` command was started as a co-process by using `|&`, and by using `exec >&p` the script redirects all output from there on to the `tail` process (only the output of `cat` in the example).

The original standard output is first saved as file descriptor 4 with `exec 4>&1` (and it's also to file descriptor 4 that `tail` writes) and later restored with `exec >&4` before the final `echo`.

Another way of writing the same thing, without all the file descriptor juggling, would be

```
tail -n 5 /etc/passwd
printf 'exitcode = %d\n' "$?"
```

(although `$exitcode` here will be the exit status of `tail` rather than of `cat`)

Comment: What if the command used here is a long running command and what is `wait` used for in that context?

Comment: @vijaysekhar The `wait` is there to ensure that the script does not progress past that point until the co-process has terminated. If the co-process is something that takes a long time to finish, then the `wait` will pause for a long time. I don't _quite_ see why you'd want to complicate the script in this manner though.

Comment: I have long running command of `nsradmin` where I have to pipe the output to get last few lines. But I am losing the return code of `nsradmin` so I am looking for this version of code. As most don't know `nsradmin` I have posted it with `cat`

Comment: @vijaysekhar If you could use `bash`, then do `nsradmin | tail -n 5`, then investigate `${PIPESTATUS[0]}`. This would be the exit status of `nsradmin`.  Alternatively, redirect the output of `nsradmin` to a temporary file, examine the exit status, _then_ run `tail` on the temporary file.